# Maven project structure for Java+JNI project

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface

The default Java Maven project structure is usually

```
src/
  main/
    java/
      org/example/Main.java
  test/
    java/
```

If I have a project with C++/JNI code, would it be right to extend on this idea and put the C++ code into the folder `src/main/cpp` or would it be usually put somewhere else? If so, what is the rationale behind the `java` folder?

Comment: I have worked on two projects (different companies) with JNI implementations; we kept the C++ code in separate repo and used the generated DLL in our Java Project.

Comment: Did you also kept the JNI interface code in the separate repository? At least that code is highly dependent on the Java code and must change whenever the package of the corresponding classes change.

Comment: To be honest I can't remember, but in general - if it was c++ it was kept in the c++ repo and java in the Java repo :)

Comment: I see. In our current project, we do exactly the same, but the JNI code is rather hardly coupled to the Java code structure, so I thought, I'd be better to put it into the Java project. However, what's the rationale of the `java` folder then? isn't it redundant then?

Comment: I don't think so, as the other folder would normally be a resource folder. So Java Code and Resources? But I am not 100% sure what the creators had in mind. I have worked with maven for 10 years now and have never questioned it :D

Comment: With no practical experience, I would have create maven 1 project with 2 Modules Then use the maven-nar-plugin to build the c++ module and just the standard for the other. This way, you don't get two build systems on the same folder structure.

Comment: Thank you for you're suggestions. You're right, the other folder is `resources`, I overlooked it when I was thinking about this question.

Comment: Little addition: When creating a C++ project in Android Studio, the default project structure is exactly as I described above. They also have a `cpp/` directory in `src/main` next to `java/` and `resources/`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of the [Maven directory structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html):

> If there are other contributing sources to the artifact build, they would be under other subdirectories. For example src/main/antlr would contain Antlr grammar definition files.

Taking into account that JNI code is also something contributing to the artifact build, that the default Android Studio project structure for Android apps with NDK also includes a folder `src/main/cpp`, and that JNI code is naturally hardly coupled with the corresponding Java class, I believe it's best to include at least the JNI code into the Java project at `src/main/cpp`. Usually, the core C/C++ library code is something generalizable, so it would be kept in a separate project and built separately.